# react-bootstrap button link onclick and href

Tags: javascript, html, react-bootstrap

I would like to trigger an image download from a react-bootstrap `Button`. The image is generated on the fly. Here is my code in the `render` method of my react component:

```
<Button
        href="#"
        ref={ (button) => { this.downloadSnapshotButton = button; } }
        type="button"
        title="Take snapshot"
        onClick={this.takeSnapShot}
        download
      />
```

Then, here is the function called in my `onClick` handler:

```
 takeSnapShot() {
    const alink = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.downloadSnapshotButton);
    alink.href = this.doTakeSnapshot();
    return true;
 }
```

The `doTakeSnapshot` function returns an image data URI in the form `data:image/jpeg...` (base64 encoded).

I am expecting to have the file download dialog popping up to download the jpeg image. But nothing happens. Any help would be appreciated !